# Swift C interop: Passing Swift Argv to C argv

Tags: swift

I am working on a swift wrapper for a C library. One such function in this library expects the command line arguments, in the form of `char const *const *`. This is linked to swift as `Optional<UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>?>>` From swift I can obtain the command line arguments as `CommandLine.unsafeArgv`, of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>`. How can I convert this to the expected immutable type? I know UnsafePointer has a constructor that takes an UnsafeMutablePointer, but I'm unsure of how to handle the nested types. Suggestions on how to correctly convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (tested with Xcode 12 / swift 5.3)

```
    let values: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>?> = 
        UnsafeRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv).bindMemory(
            to: UnsafePointer<Int8>?.self,
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)
        )

    your_api_func(Int(CommandLine.argc), values)
```

**Alternate:** (on @MartinR comment) tested & worked as well.

```
    CommandLine.unsafeArgv.withMemoryRebound(
            to: UnsafePointer<Int8>?.self, 
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)) { ptr in
        your_api_func(Int(CommandLine.argc), ptr)
    }
```

Comment: You can simplify it a bit  (and get rid of the UnsafeRawPointer ) if you use `CommandLine.unsafeArgv.withMemoryRebound(...)`